# Adding Timestamp to Database Table

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, sql

I have an html/php form that updates entries on the database server. I need to add a field to each row indicating when that entry is added, so in other words a timestamp of when the entry was created. I have been searching and found this:

http://www.createafreewebsite.net/phpmysql/alter.html

Would I do something like:

```
$timestamp = time();
mysql_query("ALTER TABLE notification
ADD timestamp CHAR(30) AFTER names);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO notification (`timestamp`) values ('$timestamp');
```

is this the correct way to approach it, and am I using the correct datatype? I would need to compare the timestamp with another timestamp generated from a javascript file later on. For example, if timestamp1 is smaller than timestamp2 than perform following functions...

Any information would be helpful, thanks!

EDIT:

Provided information as requested:

So far I have:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO notification (`program`, `month`, `day`, `year`, `sponsor`, `type`, `category`, `range`, `desc`) values ('$pName' ,  '$month' , '$day' , '$year' , '$sponsor' , '$type' , '$category' , '$range' , '$desc')");
```

Comment: Would you mind posting the structure of the table to which you're trying to add the column? Using that `INSERT` statement won't insert any data into the other columns of the table, and will fail if one or more of them is `NOT NULL` and without a default.

Comment: I've added my current insert line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`time()` in PHP will produce a timestamp, your MySQL table might be expecting another format, so you can just do:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO notification (`timestamp`) values (NOW());
```

and it will work with date and datetime fields too.

Even though your table is CHAR(30) you still have one less variable to use.

Of if you change your column data type to `TIMESTAMP` then you can use `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to fill the table cell for you.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, will this generate a numerical timestamp, or something formatted that the user can read? I'm actually thinking doing mathematical comparison would be easier with just a numerical timestamp, like `1332249169` instead of `Tue Mar 20 2012 09:02:49`.

Comment: its best to use MySQLs date formats, you can easily convert them to timestamps using `strtotime()`in PHP

Comment: Nice!, Can this `strtotime()` also be done with javascript? I'm thinking of reading the table timestamp column from the database with js and comparing it to the current time.

Comment: Well JS cant read the table without PHPs help, so you can just use strtotime() before you pass the data to the JS.

Comment: "you can use `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to fill the table cell for you." - Wouldn't that also update the column on an `UPDATE` as well as an `INSERT`? Of course, that may be what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

timestamp should have a timestamp datatype. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html

Answer (score 1):

You definitely do not want to use a column with CHAR or VARCHAR datatype to store a date or timestamp - it can make comparisons difficult later on. Also, you should consider putting a default on the `timestamp` column so that it is automatically populated when you insert a row, or using an insert trigger on the `notification` table to do the population. That way the chance of developer error is reduced.

```
CREATE TRIGGER notification_timestamp BEFORE INSERT
    ON notification FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET new.timestamp = NOW();
END;
```

Apologies if the syntax isn't quite right.

Comment: Hey thanks for the post, I'm trying to do what you suggested but I'm very new to SQL altogether. How would I 'use' your code, so far I've just been adding and editing tables with PHP code. How would the code know which column to insert the timestamp into?

Comment: In a trigger the `new` table refers to the inserted/updated data, while the `old` table refers to the data that is being updated or deleted. So by using `SET new.timestamp = NOW()` you're telling MySQL to set the value of the `timestamp` column (by the way, you may want to pick another name for the column as `timestamp` is a datatype in MySQL) to the current time (`NOW()` is a synonym for `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`) and use it for the row to be inserted.

Comment: so `CREATE TRIGGER name_of_timestamp_col BEFORE INSERT` `ON table_name FOR EACH ROW` `BEGIN` `SET new.timestamp = NOW();` `END;`